# Why is my RecyclerView rendering in my dialog window but not in the main layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app creates the following layout:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = this;
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.install_from_google_play), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/webv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/browser_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:text="@string/comments_page"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/browser_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/user_view"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/retrievedCommentsProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recent_comments_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<com.chiaramail.opencomments.MovableFloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/add_comment"
   android:visibility="visible"
   app:fabSize="normal"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus_circle"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<com.chiaramail.opencomments.MovableFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/return_to_list"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/view_list_outline"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/refresh" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevron_left_disabled" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/forward"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevron_right_disabled" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm declaring the following RecyclerView in onCreate():

```
    final ArrayList<UserComments> pageItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    itemArrayAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this, activity, pageItemList);
    user_view = findViewById(R.id.user_view);
    user_view.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
    user_view.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(activity,
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    user_view.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

The code eventually calls a method fetchComments() that loads data into pageItemList.

fetchComments():

```
    private void fetchComments(String url) {
    String extractedURL = extractSite(url);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String extractedSite = extractSite(url);
    String extractedDomain = extractDomain(url);
    // If the URL doesn't have a host name, e.g., example.com, add "www." to the url and look for
    // comments for either one.
    if (extractedSite.equals(extractedDomain)) extractedSite = "www." + extractedDomain;
    String mobileSite = "m." + extractedDomain;
    Query commentQuery = baseRef.whereIn(FSHOSTNAME, Arrays.asList(extractedSite, mobileSite, extractedDomain));

    registration = commentQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (mFirebaseUser == null || value.size() == 0) {
                if (blacklistArray.contains(extractDomain(url))) {
                    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(redToolbarColor));
                    showScamWarning(url);
                    retrieved_comments_dialog.show();
                }
                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return;
            }
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "user_ID = " + user_ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.listen_error) + BLANK + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return;
            }

            // Display the "Loading comments..." message the first time only.
            if (!registrations.containsKey(url)) Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.loading_comments), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            boolean isEmpty = true;
            ArrayList tmp = (ArrayList) docRefList.clone();
            docRefList.clear();
            userDocList.clear();
            pageURLList.clear();
            pageItemList.clear();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                if (!isSamePage(doc, url)) continue;
                // Don't include duplicates.
                for (int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++) {
                    if (!((QueryDocumentSnapshot)tmp.get(i)).getId().equals(doc.getId()) &&
                            !docRefList.contains(doc)) {
                        isEmpty = false;
                        getUserValuesForPage(doc);
                    }
                }
                if (tmp.size() == 0) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                    getUserValuesForPage(doc);
                }

            }

            // Unregister the existing listener, if any.
            if (registrations.containsKey(url)) registrations.remove(url);
            registrations.put(url, registration);
            if (isEmpty) {
                mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(defaultColor));
                color_map.put(url, defaultColor);
                pageItemList.clear();
                itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (blacklistArray.contains(extractDomain(url))) {
                    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(redToolbarColor));
                    showScamWarning(url);
                    retrieved_comments_dialog.show();
                } else {
                    // If the current page is not a search page and not a tap on the search bar, show the prompt and the green header.
                    if (!url.contains(SEARCH_PARAM)) {
                        mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(greenToolbarColor));
                        color_map.put(url, greenToolbarColor);
                    } else {
                        mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(defaultColor));
                        color_map.put(url, defaultColor);
                        pageItemList.clear();
                        itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

getUserValuesForPage():

```
    private void getUserValuesForPage(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    DocumentReference mOtherUserDocRef = db.collection(USERS).document((String)doc.get(FSUSERID));
    docRefList.add(doc);
    mOtherUserDocRef.get(Source.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>) task -> {
        //          mUserDocRef.get(Source.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot userDoc = task.getResult();
            showComment(pageItemList, itemArrayAdapter,(String)doc.getId(), (String)doc.get(FSUSERID), (String)doc.get(FSCOMMENT), (String)doc.get(FSPATH), (HashMap<String, String>)doc.get(FSSEARCH), (String)doc.get(FSSUBJECT), (Timestamp) doc.get(FSTIMESTAMP), (String)doc.get(FSURL), false, (String)userDoc.get(FSDEVICEID), (String)userDoc.get(FSNAME), (String)userDoc.get(FSPICTUREURL), (String)doc.get(FSREPLY));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.getuser_error) + BLANK + Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            crashlytics.log(context.getString(R.string.getuser_error) + BLANK + Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage());
            crashlytics.log("User ID: " + doc.get(FSUSERID));
        }
    });
}
```

showComment():

```
    private void showComment(ArrayList<UserComments> itemList, 
      RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, String docID, String uid, String comment, 
      String path, HashMap<String, String> search, String subject, Timestamp 
      timestamp, String url, boolean scam_warning, String devid, String uname, 
      String photoURL, String reply ) {
    UserComments nextComment = new UserComments();
    nextComment.user_name = (uname != null ? uname : 
      getString(R.string.anon_person));
    nextComment.device_id = devid;
    nextComment.picture = (photoURL != null ? photoURL : SILHOUETTE_URL);
    nextComment.timestamp = timestamp;
    nextComment.subject = subject;
    nextComment.docId = docID;
    nextComment.reply = reply;
    nextComment.userId = uid;
    nextComment.comment = comment;
    nextComment.site = extractSite(url);
    nextComment.page_url = url;
    nextComment.scam_warning = scam_warning;
    nextComment.path = path;
    nextComment.search = search;
    if (!commentsStack.contains(nextComment)) commentsStack.add(nextComment);
    itemList.add(commentsStack.pop());
    if (showList) {
        if (!recentCommentsShown) {
            recentCommentsSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return_to_list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            recent_comments_dialog.show();
        }
        recentCommentsShown = true;
        showList = false;
    }
    Collections.sort(itemList, new SortByTime().reversed());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    recentCommentsSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

UserComments.java:

```
public class UserComments {
Timestamp timestamp;
String  hostname;
String  path;
String  page_url;
boolean  scam_warning;
String  userUID;
String device_id;
String picture;
String docId;
String replyDocID;
String user_name;
String subject;
String reply;
String userId;
String comment;
String site;
Map     search;
}
```

I create an AlertDialog as follows:

```
    private void createRetrievedCommentsDialog(ArrayList<UserComments> list) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View dialoglayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.retrieved_comments, null);
    retrievedCommentsSpinner = dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.retrievedCommentsProgressBar);
    RecyclerView view = dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.user_view);

    itemArrayAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this, activity, list);
    view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    view.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
    builder
            .setView(dialoglayout)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton(context.getString(R.string.dismiss), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    retrieved_comments_dialog = builder.create();
    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

The app uses a boolean, autoshowComments, to control whether the screen should be split vertically into two parts, one displaying a WebView and the other showing a RecyclerView displaying a bunch of data: when autoshowComments is true, the screen is split and the data is displayed. The problem I'm facing is that if the boolean is set to true when the app is started, the data isn't displayed below the WebView, although the screen is split as expected. Moreover, if I start the app with autoshowComments false and then change it to true using a menu item,

```
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.overlay_menu).setChecked(autoshowComments);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.overlay_menu) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = browser_page.getLayoutParams();
        if (item.isChecked()) {
            item.setChecked(false);
            user_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
            browser_page.setLayoutParams(params);
            autoshowComments = false;
        } else {
            item.setChecked(true);
            user_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            params.height = Integer.valueOf((int) (WEBVIEW_HT * metrics.heightPixels));
            browser_page.setLayoutParams(params);
            autoshowComments = true;
        }
        updateAutoshow(autoshowComments);
        return true;
    }
 }
```

the data items do appear (although they don't get updated in realtime, as they should by fetchComments()):

Here's what the screen looks like when the app is started with autoshowComments set to true (nothing is displayed below "Comments for this page"):

[image]

Unchecking the box gives this (note the WebView isn't resized):
[image]

When the app is started with autoshowComments set to false, we get:
[image]

And when the box is checked:
[image]

When the box is unchecked, the page is resized, as expected.

Tapping the green titlebar displays the AlertDialog:
[image]
So my question is why pageItemList doesn't get loaded in the first case but does in the second?

Comment: Hi FractalBob, if everything works from the menu, and you execute the same logic by default when the screen starts, then you might have an issue with threads. Be sure that you are not doing anything UI-related on the background thread.

Comment: You have a lot of mixed-up logic, flags, and everything, so it's hard to say, but my first thought is that it might be related to threads.

Comment: @Haris I'm not explicitly coding any Threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
pageItemList.clear();
itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**pageItemList** need data before you call *notifyDataSetChanged*. And when I search pageItemList in your code, I don't see any line to add item into pageItemList.

check this point

Comment: The data is loaded via fetchComments(); see above.

Comment: @FractalBob, there's only `pageItemList.clear()` calls.

Comment: @ltp Please reread my question. fetchComments() loads the list. If it didn't, I wouldn't have gotten the results shown.

Comment: Oh, you passed the list to `showComment` and updated it there. It's just weird and confusing that you put the logic of updating the list inside `showComment`.  `showComment` as the method name suggest , should just show the comments list (Single Responsibility Principle)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!pageItemList.impty()){
  pageItemList.clear();
}
```

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();